# Change Read More link WordPress

Tags: wordpress, button, hyperlink

I want to change the Read More link in WordPress, i have found some tutorials where in the `<!-- more -->` i can write something else `<!-- more Proceed... -->` (this did not work). 
And in the index.php i should edit `<?php the_content('Read More..,'); ?>`, but in my index.php there is no Read More text, it looks like this `<?php the_content(''); ?>`, it is empty and it still shows Read More on posts.

Any other ideas how to change it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the

```
<?php the_content(''); ?>
```

into whatever you want. So you can make it:

```
<?php the_content('more Proceed... '); ?>
```

or whatever you want. "Read more..." is default when you leave it open.

Comment: In this case i get two Read More Links.. The old one Read More is still on the posts

Answer (score 0):

add this block of code in function.php file

```
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read more...      </a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```